# Is there a way to specify default values for null in Lodash or Underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I know the `_.defaults` function works to put default values for an object with keys that are `undefined`. However it doesn't work with keys that are `null`. Is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @Jacque for the explanation about `null` values. However due to unfortunate inherited code, the object I'm working on returns `null` values even though it's intended for `undefined`. Here's my approach in achieving this in a more declarative way by omitting the `null` properties which will result into `undefined`, as a result will create defaults for its values.

```js
const alphabet = {
  a: 'A is for apple',
  // b: undefined,
  c: 'C is for cake',
  d: null,
}
const nonNulls = _.omitBy(alphabet, _.isNull) // Omitting null values.
const longer = _.defaults(nonNulls, {
  b: 'B is for boy',
})

console.info('Longer Way', longer)

// Or even shorter
const shorter = _.defaults(_.omitBy(alphabet, _.isNull), {
  b: 'B is for boy',
})

console.info('Shorter Way', shorter)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, this gets rid of all null/NaN/undefined values and adds the defaults to the object. I didn't even think about that use case :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind this behavior for the `_.defaults` helper is that `undefined` means a property hasn't been set and `null` conveys the meaning of being explicitly set to refer to nothing.

If you still think your variables should hold `null` and be set with a function, then you can use `_.defaultTo`, a function that returns its first argument normally and its second if the first one was `NaN`, `null` or `undefined`. You'll need to make it loop over all the object's keys yourself though.

```
_.forOwn(myObject, function (value, key) {
  myObject[key] = _.defaultTo(value, defaultValues[key]);
});
```

However, this won't set values for variables that are not even defined on the original element, since we're looping through its own properties. Plus it's not very efficient. If that's what you wanted, might as well loop on the defaults instead:

```
_.forOwn(defaultValues, function (value, key) {
  if (myObject[key] === undefined || myObject[key] === null)
    myObject[key] = value;
});
```

```js
function getSampleObject() {
  return {
    a: null,
    b: NaN,
    // c: undefined,
    d: undefined,
    e: 'original'
}};

var defaultValues = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5
};

var myObject = getSampleObject();
_.forOwn(myObject, function (value, key) {
  myObject[key] = _.defaultTo(value, defaultValues[key]);
});

console.log('defaultTo', myObject);

var myObject = getSampleObject();
_.defaults(myObject, defaultValues);

console.log('defaults', myObject);

var myObject = getSampleObject();
_.forOwn(defaultValues, function (value, key) {
  if (myObject[key] === undefined || myObject[key] === null)
    myObject[key] = value;
});

console.log('handmade', myObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```